Does row order impact how a CatBoost algorithm is trained?
I'm dealing with an issue where I'm unable to replicate a particular result that I had previously obtained with CatBoost, using the same dataset (but where the rows are in different order).

First, I train a CatBoost classifier on a dataset.
I then use the same codes and the same datast (order is the same as well) to train the model. The seed is set too and in this case I'm able to perfectly replicate the results.
If I use a slightly different dataset where all the values are the same and the column order is the same but the order of rows is different, I'm getting slightly different results (>1% difference in the Model's performance metrics such as Accuracy etc.)

The dataset is fairly large (over 500k training samples & 250k validation samples). I'm using the overfitting detector using the validation dataset.
I'm suspecting that the order of rows might have an impact, but I'm not able to find any sources online to prove this. Is my suspicion right or is there something else going on?
